# Firefox: mouse right click triggers left click

Tags: firefox, click

I have a weird behavior on firefox. When I righclick anywhere, a click event is fired over the contextual menu that is displayed. (this happens only in the document itself. Not in any menu or bar.

This means (according to my contextual menu at least) that any right click on a link opens the page in an incognito window, and any right click on an empty space triggers "save as"

[image]

I have disabled all extensions, but it still happens. For the time being I've resorted to holding right button and then selecting the desired option in the contextual menu.

(PD: I saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144995/mouse-right-click-on-firefox-triggers-click-event) but the behavior is not quite the same)

Comment: This a strange phenomenon, I searched `click` in `about:config` and found nothing related to `right click`, does this happen when you use other browsers? BTW, I think people in [reddit/r/firefox](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/) is more active than SO in firefox tag.

Comment: it doesn't happen in chrome nor brave. Thanks for the reddit tip

Comment: If you are on MS-Windows, Please check the Mouse Settings. Windows provides for Mouse setting for Right Hand Users by default which can be changed for Left Hand Users wherein the Right Button behaves like Left Button and vice-versa

Comment: Thanks @Raky. It happened on Ubuntu 18. I have a different mouse, notebook and Ubuntu focal, so I guess we'll never know if any of those were to blame or my Firefox install was broken

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite issue with Firefox/macOS.
When I try to catch a `mouseup` event and `Ctrl`is pressed it returns `event.button: 2` or `event.which: 3`. I have not found any post related to it.

Chrome and Safari return 0 as it should be.

I have not figured out why.